# Wicket ImageResourceReference ist mounted multiple times everytime the page is reloaded

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket

I'm trying to mount an ImageResourceReference on my Page, but the ExternalLink is mounted multiple times (everytime I reload the page, I get a new additional link (same one).
For example when I start the server and load the page for the first time, there's just one ExternalLink, the second time, two links, third time three, etc...

What could be the reason for that?

Here is my code: 
WebApp.java:

```
void init() {
.....
mountResource("/book/number/${number}/images/ray/${name}", new ImageResourceReference());
....
}
```

ImageResourcesPanel:

```
public class ImageResourcesPanel extends Panel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8723530004274531683L;
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImageResourcesPanel.class
            .getName());

    /**
     * The image names for which dynamic images will be generated
     */
    private static List<String> IMAGE_NAMES = new ArrayList<String>(); 


    public ImageResourcesPanel(final String wicketId, final IModel<Device> model) {
        super(wicketId, model);

        String pathToImage = "images";
        IMAGE_NAMES.add(pathToImage);

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>("list", IMAGE_NAMES) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {

                logger.debug("Executed!");

                ResourceReference imagesResourceReference = new ImageResourceReference();
                PageParameters imageParameters = new PageParameters();


                int number = model.getObject().getNumber();
                String imageName = item.getModelObject();
                String folder = model.getObject().getLinkToFolder();
                imageParameters.set("name", imageName);
                imageParameters.set("number", number);
                imageParameters.set("folder", folder);

                // generates nice looking url (the mounted one) to the current image
                CharSequence urlForWordAsImage = getRequestCycle().urlFor(imagesResourceReference, imageParameters);
                ExternalLink link = new ExternalLink("link", urlForWordAsImage.toString());
                link.setBody(Model.of(imageName));
                item.add(link);

            }
        };
        add(listView);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please provide: Panel markup, produced erroneous html, desired html.

Comment: Hi, I am using a similar code and when the page loads , I am getting following exception. WicketObjects : Could not resolve class [undefined]
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: undefined
 at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
 at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I just had to make the ListView empty after mounting the image on the page. I just added a line of code after adding the link to the ListView-Item:

```
`IMAGE_NAMES.remove(pathToImage);`
```